# Angular Error in Inspect dev tools - No unique element matched for signature - content.js

Tags: angular

When starting new angular app I get this error in chrome dev tools. How do I fix or remove this error.

content.js:1102 2022-02-24T21:11:55 ERROR [Page], [WebDocumentCompleteTrigger::handleTrigger] No unique element matched for signature =
/child::html/child::html/descendent::form/descendent::input[@tag_name="input" and @type="password"]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you try and open it in another browser or chrome in incognito modus? It might be a chrome plugin by the looks of it.

Comment: I'm using my work laptop(proxy firewall), not sure if that has anything to so with it. When I'm in incognito mode, the errors are gone.  The errors show in Firefox as well so its not chrome related.

When I use my personal desktop I don't see these errors in console.